# apache2 returning PHP source instead of executing it

Tags: apache2, raspbian, php-7

I installed apache2 and php7 on a raspberry pi 3 (running raspbian jessie), but when I visit a webpage, it returns the php source code instead of executing it.

PHP 7 seems to be installed properly...

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.15-1 (cli) (built: Jan 25 2017 10:17:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I run sudo `a2enmod php7.0` I get `ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!`.

When I try installing it (`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`), I get this issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but 2.4.10-10+deb8u7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried re-installing apache2, but nothing seems to work. Web pages still return the php source instead of executing it.

Comment: Have you run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade?

Comment: I have. I also tried `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and have added `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi` to my sources list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`).

Answer (score 0):

Something about your apache install is not quite right, try this:

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest trying `apt-get remove apache2`